# How should I pass a large amount of Redux actions from a container to presentational component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following container component which is connected to the Redux store. I wish to pass six actions to the LayerList presentational component.

*LayerListContainer.jsx*

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import LayerList from '../components/LayerList'

// import actions 
import * as LayerActions from '../actions/index'

export const LayerListContainer = ({ layers }) => (
    <div>
     <LayerList layers={layers} /* I want to pass actions to this component/>
    </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  layers: state.layers
})

// Use default export for the connected component (for app)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, LayerActions)(LayerListContainer)
```

Here are the actions I wish to pass:

*actions/index.js*

```
export const addLayer = (name) => ({
    type: ADD_LAYER,
    id: nextLayerId++,
    name,
})

export const removeLayer = (id) => ({
    type: REMOVE_LAYER,
    id
})

export const toggleDragLayer = (id) => ({
    type: TOGGLE_DRAG_LAYER,
    id
})

export const moveLayerIndex = (id, destinationIndex) => ({
    type: MOVE_LAYER_INDEX,
    id,
    destinationIndex
})

export const updateLayerColour = (id, colour) => ({
    type: UPDATE_LAYER_COLOUR,
    id,
    colour
})

export const toggleLayerVisibility = (id) => ({
    type: TOGGLE_LAYER_VISIBILITY,
    id
})
```

Perhaps you don't consider this to be a large amount of actions. If not I would still be interested to know what best practices are for future reference on passing many actions from a container component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass every properties of your container to your presentational using the `...` spread operator syntax like this

```
export const LayerListContainer = props => (
  <div>
    <LayerList {...props} />
  </div>
);
```

Or if you just want to pass actions, you have to use `bindActionCreators`

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

// ...

export const LayerListContainer = ({ layers, actions }) => (
  <div>
    <LayerList layers={layers} actions={actions} />
  </div>
);

// ..

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ 
  actions: bindActionCreators(LayerActions, dispatch)
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LayerListContainer)
```

Comment: Will that pass dispatch along with the action creators?

Comment: What is the purpose of the first section of the answer as the question was specifically regarding action creators and not other kinds of props?

Comment: On another note that first code block will not work. You cannot reference 'this' in a stateless react component as it is just a function. In order to use 'this' you need to use the class based syntax for components.

Comment: You're right, see my edit. The point of the first part of my answer is : this is the simple way to just pass all your actions down to your presentational component. It will be the best way unless you don't want to pass some properties to your presentational for any reasons.

Comment: I prefer give you options than a solution who 'just works'

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your effort, we all make mistakes.